# Finding "unanswered" comments

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm dealing with a horribly designed table here and can't figure out a faster query. The current query, written by the previous dev, takes 20 seconds to run.

There are 18k records called "notes", with a topic_id, date, and urgency level. I need all the records that are considered "urgent". For a note to be urgent, it must have an urgency level of 2. However, a note is considered not-urgent if, since the most recent level-2 note, there has been a level 3, 4, or 5 note on the same topic. In other words, when a topic gets a level 2 note, it is considered urgent, until it gets a level 3, 4, or 5 note. If it receives another note, it is again considered urgent.

I need to get all of the urgent notes. In my head, it's something like this:

- Group the notes by their order_id.
- Filter out any groups that don't have a note with a level 2 urgency.
- Select only those groups whose most-recent level 2, 3, 4, or 5 note
  is not a 2.

As far as I can tell, the 18k records all relate to 1k topics. Then I'll be checking each groups members, filtering the groups down to only those who, at some point, have had an urgent note. Finally, I'll be finding the newest note that is either level 2, 3, 4, or 5... If it's a 2, return it, because that means it has an unresolved note. Otherwise, discard it.

Any ideas?

Edit: I believe I found a solution...

```
SELECT *, MAX(note_date) AS recent FROM ace_rp_notes n

LEFT JOIN ace_rp_orders o
ON n.order_id = o.id

WHERE n.urgency_id IN (2,3,4,5)

GROUP BY order_id
HAVING urgency_id = 2
AND recent = n.note_date
```

It takes no time at all.

Comment: can you add the current query to the question?

Comment: Also when you refer to note do you mean topic because in a table of notes every record should in theory be a note. So I presume you mean you want to find an urgent topic and a topic is urgent when its latest note is of level 2?

Comment: Can we summarise like this: "Return all notes where the most recent note with an `urgency_id` of 2 is not followed by an `urgency_id` of 3, 4 or 5."?

Comment: No fair solving this while I was typing it out ! :) You should add your solution as an answer though. Not in the question.

Comment: gvee, absolutely. Well-worded.

Murdock, you are correct, but I do want to return the urgent note, not the urgen topic.

Comment: Actually, what's the unique key to the notes table? Does note_date have enough granularity or does it only contain dates (and no times)?

Comment: Hmm... It might be granular enough to be a key now, but that might change later. I could index by order_id, I think that would help the speed?

Answer (score 0):

I'd take the following approach:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM ace_rp_notes AS n
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT order_id, max(note_date) as maxdate
    FROM ace_rp_notes
    GROUP BY order_id
    HAVING urgency_id = 2
) AS md
    ON  n.order_id = md.order_id
    AND n.note_date = md.maxdate
```

The subquery gets the last note of each topic, then join that with the notes to get the urgency of the last ticket, then filter on 2 to effectively require that the last note on a topic is an urgency 2 one to qualify the record to be in the SELECT.

**EDIT:** Optimization with HAVING in the subquery instead of out of it.

Comment: This query took 1.5 seconds, mine took .1 seconds. I think the main difference is that you're inner-joining two large tables, whereas I just use HAVING to filter the table AFTER finding the latest note for each group.

Comment: Good point, if I'd have used HAVING in my subquery the inner join would only need to join with the relevant records. I'll modify it so you'll have an answer to accept.

Comment: This doesn't actually seem to work. I end up with some notes with urgency_id=3... The query should only ever return notes with urgency_id=2, ie, unresolved urgent notes.